# custom control and events in Silverlight - racing condition?

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, xaml, binding

Unfortunately, I can't give good code sample and scenario to reproduce but I hope someone had same issue before.

Basically, what I experience is behavior where property changed doesn't get raised from my VM into bound property.

```
<IdattControls:IdattLookup 
                Name="DeviceLookup"
                DataProvider="{Binding DeviceIdLookupProvider}"
                Id="{Binding CurrentItem.DeviceId, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
                NextFocusableControl="{Binding ElementName=SerialNumberTextBox}"
                IsEnabled="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource NavigatorEnabledConverter}}"
                Type="Navigator"
                Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TabIndex="1" >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="NavigationCompleted">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding NavigatorPopulatedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id, ElementName=DeviceLookup}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>                
            </IdattControls:IdattLookup>
```

When `NavigationCompleted` event get fired inside my custom control (`IdattLookup`) - view model does some actions (makes async call to service, get's data, etc) and on async operation completion it changes `State` property.

IdattLookup doesn't get this `State`.

**Important and weird** that when I try to step through code where propertychanged raises - it WORKS. But if I run it without breakpoints my control stays enabled - never register property change. Converter doesn't get called, etc.

I'm just guessing it's got to be something with event and threads but not sure how to properly debug and fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong but still don't understand why.

IsEnabled property wasn't my `new` property. I just relied on Control's property.
For some reason propertyChanged wasn't raised on it. Now, after I created my own - it magically started to work. It almost behaved like Mode=OneTime. But sometime it magically worked..

Answer (score 0):

> It's helpful to debug whether to bind or not.
>   At Visual studio 2010,
>   Firstly you can go Menu->Tools->Options->Debugging->OutputWindow.
>   and then at WPF Trace Setting you can changte Data Binding's value to 'All' to see whether to bind or not at outputwindow.